# По признанию - вводное?

Tags: пунктуация

Является ли вводным "по признанию" в предложении: "По признанию музыкальной общественности(,) выступления этих исполнителей стали художественным откровением".

Answer (score 4):

"По... общественности" - вводное словосочетание, указывающее на источник сообщения, и оно отделяется запятой. Из Розенталя (СПРАВОЧНИК ПО ПРАВОПИСАНИЮ, ПРОИЗНОШЕНИЮ, ЛИТЕРАТУРНОМУ РЕДАКТИРОВАНИЮ, 1999; глава XXVI §99. Вводные слова и словосочетания, см. п. 1, 2):
http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/47.htm